# PlayFramework Result with Ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, playframework

According to : [PlayFramework Document 2.0](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html) &  [PlayFramework Document 2.1](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaActions)

I know that in play I can return:

```
Ok()
badRequest()
created()
status()
forbidden()
internalServerError()
TODO
```

etc...

I would like to send with ajax an response with my information in it. Unfortunatelly play sends only status information, and some kind of object which I do not understand.
Only method `ok("Test message")` sends status and my message information. Rest of it dosnt work. 
How to deal with it?

-- Edit --

I have ajax method:

```
$.post($("#assignmentsubmitAddress").text(), { 'units' : submittedUnits },
  function(response, status, xhr) {
showNotyfication(status, response);
  })
```

When I `return ok("test");`
In java script variable `response` I have just String `test`

When I `return badRequest("test");` In java script variable response I have java object. When I print variable `response` I am getting `Object object`.

Comment: Please add more information about how do you fill this response in other cases and how does this "some kind of object" look like?

Answer (score 0):

To send back a response in the json format to your client send a ok containing a string :

```
/**
 * Translate a json object into a json string.
 */
public static<T> String objToJson(Object obj)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try{
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
        return json;
    }catch(java.io.IOException e){
        Logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return "";
}

public static Result actions()
{
    Object objToSendBack = ...
    return ok(objToJson(objToSendBack));
}
```

You can send back wathever you want, including html, but json is more convenient for communicating with javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

I've figure it out.

I've just changed variable `response` which is an **object** to `response.responseText`.

Now it works.